# Can I delete pictures on my old iPhone through my new one using the same iCloud?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

My mom got a hold of my phone and I need to delete some pictures is there anyway I can do so even if it means that I'll have to delete all my pictures?

Answer (score 1):

If both devices have the **same iCloud credentials** *and* **iCloud Photo Library** is **on** in both of them, deletions are synced between devices.
The same principle applies to My Photo Stream.

You can even delete the images on iCloud, no need for a second iPhone.

You can download them from iCloud or copy them to a computer from the second device before deleting them.

If you are worried that someone may see them at all, go to the "Recently deleted" album and delete them from there as well.

The iPhone you want images to be remotely deleted on must connect to internet for this changes to occur.